# JerseyClient async calls seems to leave hanging threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey-client

I'm using jersey-client-3.0-SNAPSHOT.

I do something like:

```
 final Client client = createClient();
```

...

```
    Builder builder = target.request();
    for (final Entry<String, String> entry : getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        builder = builder.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    final Builder finalBuilder = builder;
    executor.submit(() -> {
        final Entity<?> entity = createPostEntity();
        futureResponse = finalBuilder.async().post(entity);
        try {
            response = futureResponse.get(TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            consumeResponse(response);
        } catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            errorConsumer.accept(e);
        }
    });

    if (futureResponse != null) {
        try {
            futureResponse.cancel(true);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            //does nothing, now we try keep closing resources
        }
    }
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            response.close();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            //does nothing, now we try keep closing resources
        }
    }
```

... //wait for responses and read or whatever

```
client.close();
```

And a new thread keeps appearing each time a create and destroy one of those clients.

Is there a safe way on destroying those threads?
Is this an expected behaviour?
Am a doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `asynchronous` calls in `Jersey client`, whenever we call `close()` on `client` object, it destroys the `thread` used in `async` calling. So, it is expected behavior that whenever `client.close()` statement will get executed, it will destroy the thread and next time, a new thread will get created for next `async` call.

Now, one of the safe way to close `client` object and associated thread considering error scenario is below -

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(SERVER_URL).path(API_PATH);

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    // set headers and other stuff

    AsyncInvoker asyncInvoker = invocationBuilder.async();

    asyncInvoker.get(new InvocationCallback<Response>() {

        @Override
        public void completed(Response response) {
            if (response.getStatusInfo().equals(Status.OK)) {
               // parse the response in success scenario
            } else {
               // parse the response if error response is received from server
            }
            client.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred while calling API");
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            client.close();
        }
    });
```