# How to increase timeout while making a REST call from a Java jersey client?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client, connection-timeout

I am making a REST call which takes around 2 or 3 minutes to respond, but I am getting a connect timed out exception. How do I increase the timeout for the REST call that is being made.

Here is the code snippet,

```
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(requestURL);
    ClientResponse response =  webResource.accept("application/json").header("Authorization", authStringEnc)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response.getStatus() != 200)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }
```

Kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the connection timeout with Jersey 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543209/how-to-set-the-connection-timeout-with-jersey-2)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can change the request header like:

> Connection: Keep-Alive Keep-Alive: timeout= set_your_desired_time
>   limit

Comment: @dwarakeshtp can you accept this as an answer if this worked for you. So that it is helpful for others