# Timeout per Request in RestEasy

Tags: jersey, timeout, jax-rs, resteasy

I am looking to set timeout for every request object in RestEasy.
Jersey gives the same functionality through request properties. Please refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056418

```
   // overriden timeout value for this request
   request.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 500);
   request.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 500);
```

I couldn't find similar feature for RestEasy. The feature to configure it per Client is available, but because of the framework we use the Client is instantiated at startup & reused for all requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As explained on jboss v7.3 by [redhat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/index) :

> - The **connectTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait when making a new server connection.
> - The **readTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait for a response from the server.

So this should be good for your case:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
           .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .build();
```